# Discrete math example clarification (stars and bars)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

Example 6.3.4 from Discrete Mathematics by Richard Johnsonbaugh 8th ed, page 285 (abridged):

"Consider three books: a computer science book, a physics book, and a history book. Suppose that the library has at least six copies of each of these books. In how many ways can we select six books?

Let us denote a particular selection as

```
 CS   Physics  History
 ××× |  ××    | ×
```

But this is just the number of ways C(8, 2) = 28 of selecting two positions for the |’s from eight possible positions."

My question, why 8 positions? Surely there are 5 positions if the bars have to be inside the x and 7 positions if they can be on the outside of x?

Comment: You've got eight symbols; the six stars and the two bars. You get to choose which two of the eight symbols will be bars.

Comment: Thanks, I think that helped. I'm becoming more sane. Saner, you could say.